# How do I add a "Projects" section to the LinkedIn profile page?

Tags: linkedin

I saw many times pages with a *Projects* section, like this:

https://www.linkedin.com/in/christopher-phillippi-05633167

See "Background" supersection and "Projects" subsection in it.

Unfortunately, on my page

https://www.linkedin.com/in/dimskraft

I am unable to do this. I have read that there should be some "Projects" buttons at the right, but I can't find them on my page.

What does this depend on?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you're logged into your account. :)

If you go to your profile, just under your profile picture you should have this:

[image]

Click on  `View More` and you should have the `Add project` button, like this:

[image]

You can link your projects with jobs, people, external links, etc.